Why does the USD value no longer appear for a certain token in the phantom app?
It used to be accounted for in my wallet balance and show the value when sending to others but not anymore. Why might this have happened?

Two reasons that are possible.
The API that fetches the prices did not respond in a timely manner to Phantom so it's displayed as null
Unlikely but you might have a unofficial USDC token; ensure it's address is EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v
